# "the girls' nose" or "the girls' noses": which means the nose of many girls?

Tags: grammatical-number, apostrophe, syntactic-analysis, saxon-genitive

"the girls' nose" or "the girls' noses"?

We are talking about the nose of many girls.

Answer (score 3):

Girls' noses. "Girls' nose" would only occur if many girls were sharing the same nose, which is uncommon to say the least.

Comment: Consider, however, the three Graeae, who shared one eye and one tooth among them. :)

Comment: Feel free to consider inventing Greek words for their nose, then. Sounds like phun.

Comment: @JohnLawler A monorhis? And the ladies themselves were koinorhinic?

Comment: Nah, I bet it'd be monorhine, and the h would be misspelled more often than not. If it ever caught on, that is.

Comment: There was a class project to make a giant sculpture of a head, à la Mt. Rushmore.  The students divided into groups to produce portions of the face.  The girls’ nose was picked by the judges as the best in the class.